# ViewBag llega vacío

Tags: visual-studio, asp.net-mvc

Tengo un formulario en donde se registrara una Charla en la base de datos, todo funciona bien, el problema es el ViewBag, ya que este lleva el mensaje a Javascript en la vista para que pueda colocar una validación. Cuando el usuario registra, le debe aparecer un mensaje success, pero por el ViewBag hace que aparezca como error, en la base de datos si se muestra los datos del usuario, asi que el único problema seria el ViewBag.

Además, cuando vuelvo a ejecutar nuevamente, recién me aparece bien el modal con el mensaje success.

**Controlador**

```
//Charlas
    public ActionResult CrearCharla()
    {
        List<ClsSede> listaSede = new List<ClsSede>();

        ClsSede Sede1 = new ClsSede();
        Sede1.sede_Text = "LIMA - SAN BORJA";
        Sede1.sede_Value = "LIMA - SAN BORJA";

        ClsSede Sede2 = new ClsSede();
        Sede2.sede_Text = "LIMA - LOS OLIVOS";
        Sede2.sede_Value = "LIMA - LOS OLIVOS";

        ClsSede Sede3 = new ClsSede();
        Sede3.sede_Text = "LIMA - CHORRILLOS";
        Sede3.sede_Value = "LIMA - CHORRILLOS";

        listaSede.Add(Sede1);
        listaSede.Add(Sede2);
        listaSede.Add(Sede3);

        ViewBag.Sedes = new SelectList(listaSede, "sede_Text", "sede_Value");

        return View(new ClsCharla());
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult CrearCharla(ClsCharla charla)
    {

        List<ClsSede> listaSede = new List<ClsSede>();

        ClsSede Sede1 = new ClsSede();
        Sede1.sede_Text = "LIMA - SAN BORJA";
        Sede1.sede_Value = "LIMA - SAN BORJA";

        ClsSede Sede2 = new ClsSede();
        Sede2.sede_Text = "LIMA - LOS OLIVOS";
        Sede2.sede_Value = "LIMA - LOS OLIVOS";

        ClsSede Sede3 = new ClsSede();
        Sede3.sede_Text = "LIMA - CHORRILLOS";
        Sede3.sede_Value = "LIMA - CHORRILLOS";

        listaSede.Add(Sede1);
        listaSede.Add(Sede2);
        listaSede.Add(Sede3);

        ViewBag.Sedes = new SelectList(listaSede, "sede_Text", "sede_Value", charla.sede_Charla);

        //-----

        string mensaje = "";

        try
        {
            ClsConexion con = new ClsConexion();
            var Cnx = con.Conexion();

            OracleCommand cmd = new OracleCommand("SIMEXA_SP_REGISTRAR_CHARLA", Cnx);
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            cmd.Parameters.Add(new OracleParameter("param_titulo", OracleDbType.Varchar2)).Value = charla.titulo_Charla.Trim();
            cmd.Parameters.Add(new OracleParameter("param_descrip", OracleDbType.Varchar2)).Value = charla.descrip_Charla.Trim();
            cmd.Parameters.Add(new OracleParameter("param_fecha", OracleDbType.Varchar2)).Value = charla.fecha_Charla;
            cmd.Parameters.Add(new OracleParameter("param_hora", OracleDbType.Varchar2)).Value = charla.hora_Charla;
            cmd.Parameters.Add(new OracleParameter("param_lugar", OracleDbType.Varchar2)).Value = charla.lugar_Charla.Trim();
            cmd.Parameters.Add(new OracleParameter("param_sede", OracleDbType.Varchar2)).Value = charla.sede_Charla;
            cmd.Parameters.Add(new OracleParameter("param_requisito", OracleDbType.Varchar2)).Value = charla.requisito_Charla.Trim();
            Cnx.Open();

            OracleTransaction tx = Cnx.BeginTransaction();
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            tx.Commit();

            Cnx.Close();
            cmd.Dispose();
            Cnx.Dispose();

            mensaje = "exito";

        }
        catch
        {
            mensaje = "error";
        }
        finally
        {
            ViewBag.mensaje = mensaje;
        }

        return RedirectToAction("MostraCharlas");

    }
```

**Vista**

```
    @model wsCharlas.Models.ClsCharla

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Crear Charla";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}

<h2>Crear Charla:</h2>

@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

    <h4>Aquí usted podrá colocar todos los datos respectivos de la charla que desee crear.</h4>
    <hr />

    @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })

    <!--    <div class="form-horizontal"> -->
    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.ID_Charla, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label" })
        <div>
            @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.ID_Charla, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.ID_Charla, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.titulo_Charla, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label" })
        <div>
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.titulo_Charla, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", maxlength = "40" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.titulo_Charla, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.descrip_Charla, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label" })
        <div>
            @Html.TextAreaFor(model => model.descrip_Charla, new { @id = "textArea", @class = "form-control", maxlength = "530" })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.descrip_Charla, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.fecha_Charla, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label" })
        <div>
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.fecha_Charla, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.fecha_Charla, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.hora_Charla, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label" })
        <div>
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.hora_Charla, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.hora_Charla, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.lugar_Charla, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label" })
        <div>
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.lugar_Charla, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", maxlength = "100" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.lugar_Charla, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.sede_Charla, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label" })
        <div>
            @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.sede_Charla, (SelectList)ViewBag.Sedes, "Seleccione una Sede", new { @class = "form-control" })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.sede_Charla, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.requisito_Charla, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label" })
        <div>
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.requisito_Charla, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", maxlength = "100" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.requisito_Charla, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-md-offset-2">
            <input type="submit" value="Crear Charla" id="id_charla"  class="btn btn-success" />
        </div>
    </div>
    <!--</div> -->
}

<div>
    @Html.ActionLink("Regresar", "MostraCharlas", null, new { @class = "btn btn-primary" })
</div>

@section Scripts {
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
}

<style>
    #textArea{
        min-height: 62px;
        max-height: 135px;
    }
</style>

<script>

    var msg = '@ViewBag.mensaje'

    $("#id_charla").on("click", function () {
        if (msg == 'exito') {
            Swal.fire(
                        msg,
                        'Se agrego una nueva charla!',
                        'success'
                     )
        } else {
            Swal.fire(
                        msg,
                        'No se pudo registrar su nueva charla, asegúrese de completar todo el formulario, si el problema continua comuniquese con el área de informática!',
                        'error'
                     )
        }   
    });

</script>
```

Comment: ¿De casualidad has visto la documentación de aspnet mvc donde especifican ViewBag, ViewData y TempData?

Comment: @fredyfx sabía que la había visto en algún lugar :P

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Lo que te está pasando es que estas haciendo un redirect, y al hacer esto tu ViewBag no se mantiene. Es decir, el ViewBag se vuelve null cuando haces un redirect o una segunda llamada.

Lo que necesitas es meter ese valor en el TempData y en tu segundo action method lo recuperas, algo así como:

```
[HttpPost]
public IActionResult CrearCharla(ClsCharla charla)
{
    TempData["mensaje"] = "Hello word!!";
    return RedirectToAction("MostraCharlas");
}

public IActionResult MostraCharlas(...)
{
    if (TempData["mensaje"] != null)
        ViewBag.mensaje = TempData["mensaje"];
    return View();
}
```

Comment: Es importante mencionar que `TempData` solo tiene un tiempo de vida de dos redirecciones, `ViewBag` solo se mantiene hacia la siguiente interacción con la vista, después de eso se destruye, por eso el error y la aclaración para dejar claro que sí, en este caso le va a funcionar `TempData` pero con algunas limitaciones

Comment: Hola amigo @KodiakMx, lo que yo quiero es que ese dato sea dirigido a la vista CrearCharla, ya que ahí tengo una validación en donde el usuario podrá ver si se registro con exito o con error, pero pasarlo de MostraCharlas a la Vista CrearCharla no creo que se pueda.

Comment: Acabo de utilizar TempData envés de ViewBag en la Vista y no tuve éxito :( . Me parece rarísimo que no funcione si es en otros ActionResult tengo implementados multiples viewBag y funcionan correctamente. ¿O será por javascript ?

Comment: tambien intenta investigar como obtener informacion  usando javascript llamadas ajas, por ahora cargas nuevamente la pagina solo para obtener los datos de charla.

Comment: @GianFrancoAlexisPomaVidal me ayudas a entender tu flujo? Lo que estas buscando es algo así como CrearCharla (vacio) -> CrearCharla (con los datos y el mensaje) -> MostrarCharlas ?

Comment: Al parecer el problema era que al mandar el ViewBag lo estaba mandando en el get y NO en el post, es por eso que a la segunda vez que ejecutaba recién me salia el mensaje de validación correcta.